# C++ Dynamic template parameter based on subclass type

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I'm currently working in a first C++ project as an attempt to learn the language through experience. It has been quite challenging but up until now I've managed to tackle most problems by myself and the help of the internet.
However, as of recently I am stuck on something for which I simply cannot find a satisfying solution so I would like to hear the opinion of more experienced programmers.

The problem is the following:

- On one hand I have an abstract `BaseShape` class from which several concrete classes inherit such as `Triangle`, `Circle`, `Rectangle`, etc.
- On the other hand I have a template `RenderCommand<Shape>` class which has a specialized definition for each **concrete** shape.
- Finally I have an array that contains multiple mixed shapes as `BaseShape` pointers.

My question now is what would be the best way to create specialized `RenderCommand` instances from these `BaseShape` pointers? I am currently thinking of either dynamic casting or trying some polymorphism with virtual methods but neither feel right.

**EDIT**
For now I've settled with a solution that does the trick but I am aware that it is likely not following several best practices so I am still open to other suggestions.

To clarify things a bit I've also added some pseudocode explaining a bit the layout of the class definitions.

`RenderCommands.h`

```
struct BaseRenderCommand
{
  virtual execute() = 0;
  ... // contains stuff on cameras and other render options
}

template<class Shape>
struct RenderCommand : public BaseRenderCommand
{
  RenderCommand(Shape *shape) {...};
  virtual execute();
  ...
}
```

`Shapes.h`

```
struct BaseShape
{
  ...  // Typical shape info like center position
}

struct Triangle : public BaseShape
{
  ...
}

struct Circle : public BaseShape
{
  ...
}

struct Rectangle : public BaseShape
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't each shape know how to render itself?  Why not store a `RenderCommand<Derived>` instance as a `private` instance member in each shape (i.e. `Circle`). Then expose a pure `virtual` function `render` in the `BaseShape` which is then overridden in the derived shapes. You've programmed yourself in to a bit of a corner by using polymorphism and storing each derived shape as a base pointer in your `array`.

Comment: Yeah having a function inside the shapes to generate a specialized `RenderCommand` might be the way to go. The only thing I don't like about it is that I have to forward declare `RenderCommand` in this case.

To provide some context to how this code came about: initially the shapes had their own `render` function that contained all the rendering logic. But since then I decided to implement the Command Pattern into my code and thought it would be a good idea to move all the rendering logic into these command classes

Comment: Hers is another thought. Instead of storing an `array` of `BaseShape`'s why not store an `array` of `std::variant<Triangle, Circle, Rectangle>`. Then you can use `std::visit` with specialized lambdas to create and execute each specialized `RanderCommand`.

Comment: C++ is a multi-paradigm language, but you are mixing the paradigms too boldly. Either your `Shape` is an *open-world* object-oriented hierarchy, where you are supposed to and encouraged to add shapes freely without ever revising existing code, or it is a *closed-world* algebraic-type-like collection of classes, where each change is an extraordinary event that requires you to revisit *all the code*. Make your choice and stick to it. If you want the first option, then `Render` should be a virtual member function of `Shape`, not a template. With the second option you don't even need a base class.

Comment: Oh your `RenderCommand` is a class and not a function. Why? Does it have more than one member function? Does it have any member data? If so, please show its definition (possibly as pseudocode).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could potentially tackle this. I'm moving you away from a runtime construct (`polymorphism`) to a compile time construct `std::variant`.

Without any code I have to make a ton of assumptions here. Also note that I included the base `Shape` `class` but it is completely unnecessary in the example I provided.

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

struct Shape {
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
};

struct Square : public Shape {};
struct Triangle : public Shape {};
struct Circle : public Shape {};

template<typename T>
struct RenderCommand {
    void render(const T&) {}
};

/* Your RenderCommand specializations here. */

using Shapes = std::variant<Square, Triangle, Circle>;

int main() 
{
    std::vector<Shapes> shapes {Square{}, Triangle{}, Circle{}};
    for (const auto& shape : shapes) 
    {
        std::visit(overload{
            [](const Square& s) { RenderCommand<Square>{}.render(s); },
            [](const Triangle& t) { RenderCommand<Triangle>{}.render(t); },
            [](const Circle& c) { RenderCommand<Circle>{}.render(c); }
        }, shape);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to lean close to the dynamic casting solution I had in my head. My only gripe with this is if I were to add more shapes, I would have to update the `std::variant` and add extra lines in `std::visit` to include the new subclasses. Then again, maybe the constraints to this problem are too strong to have 'elegant' solution.

Comment: "I'm moving you away" Please don't. `std::variant` is too fashionable right now. Use it with a good dose of caution. It doesn't make sense everywhere, and it doesn't make a lot of sense here.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. why? The alternate is my first suggestion where each Shape knows how to render itself. The OP wasn’t fond of the idea .

Comment: @MrCoke I think if that’s your concern than having each shape know how to render itself is the best option for you

Comment: "The OP wasn’t fond of the idea" The original idea is just fine. Perhaps OP's un-fondness is based on some misconception that we ought to find and dispel.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I find your comment “use it with a good dose of caution” perplexing. Are you suggesting that runtime polymorphism is some how safer than a variant? Really curious on why you believe that. In my opinion there are far more foot guns using polymorphism, but I’d like to hear why you believe otherwise.

Comment: Please, there is no need to fight over this. To me this is a valid alternate solution, I am mostly trying to see the positives and negatives to each approach in order to make a choice that suits me best.

Comment: Runtime polymorphism has its place and the variant has its place. It's not like one is safer or easier or cleaner than the other. It's about the right tool for the job. I believe that under the open-world assumption (that is, we expect many new shapes to be added as the software develops), runtime polymorphism is the natural choice because it leads to better maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and decided to build something similar to the [first suggestion given by WBuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343545/c-dynamic-template-parameter-based-on-subclass-type/73344002#comment129524573_73343545). One piece of information that I forgot to include in the original answer is that `RenderCommand<Shape>` also inherits from an abstract base class `BaseRenderCommand` with a pure virtual `execute()` function.

The solution I decided upon looks something like this:

`RenderCommands.h`

```
struct BaseRenderCommand
{
  virtual execute() = 0;
  ...
}

template<class Shape>
struct RenderCommand : public BaseRenderCommand
{
  RenderCommand(Shape *shape) {...};
  virtual execute();
  ...
}
```

`RenderCommands.cpp`

```
#include "RenderCommands.h"
#include "Shapes.h"

void RenderCommand<Triangle>::execute()
{
  ...
}

void RenderCommand<Circle>::execute()
{
  ...
}

void RenderCommand<Rectangle>::execute()
{
  ...
}
```

`Shapes.h`

```
#include RenderCommands.h

struct BaseShape
{
  virtual BaseRenderCommand *create_cmd() = 0;
  ...
}

struct Triangle : public BaseShape
{
  virtual BaseRenderCommand *create_cmd();
  ...
}

struct Circle : public BaseShape
{
  virtual BaseRenderCommand *create_cmd();
  ...
}

struct Rectangle : public BaseShape
{
  virtual BaseRenderCommand *create_cmd();
  ...
}
```

`Shapes.cpp`

```
#include "Shapes.h"

BaseRenderCommand *Triangle::create_cmd()
{
  return RenderCommand<Triangle>(this);
}

BaseRenderCommand *Circle::create_cmd()
{
  return RenderCommand<Circle>(this);
}

BaseRenderCommand *Rectangle::create_cmd()
{
  return RenderCommand<Rectangle>(this);
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <vector>
#include "RenderCommands.h"
#include "Shapes.h"

std::vector<BaseShape*> shapes = new std::vector<BaseShape*>();
std::vector<BaseRenderCommand*> renderCmds = new std::vector<BaseRenderCommand*>();

...

for (auto shape : shapes)
{
  renderCmds.push_back(shape->create_cmd())
}
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear why you need `RenderCommand` at all.

Comment: Assuming you need it, which is a bold assumption that is not supported by the code shown, a container of `RenderCommand`s that has types parallel to those in the vector of `Shape`s is not a good idea. You cannot statically guarantee that `renderCmds[i]` will stay appropriate for `shapes[i]`. This means your types don't do their job.

Comment: I explained in an earlier comment that this code is a result of me intially putting the render code in the shape classes but then decided that I wanted to implement the Command Pattern design and so decided to move the render logic to a separate RenderCommand class. In the greater scope, shapes are not the only things that can be rendered. There's fonts and sprites and such as well.

Comment: As a side note. You don't need to dynamically allocate the `std::vector`'s. If you're coming from another language like `C#` this is a common mistake.

Comment: I think you misunderstand Command Pattern. Having an abstract Render command and then different concrete Render subclasses rendering different shapes is not the right application of this design pattern.

Comment: A right Command Pattern application would be having an abstract command class and then concrete commands doing different things like render, transform, save, clone...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some misconceptions about the Command Pattern. Using a command pattern doesn't mean you need to use things like `class Command` or `Command::Execute()`. All you need is a `std::function` or a lambda.

And you should not have `Shape::create_cmd()`. Instead, command should be an assignable variable in your `Shape` class, so you can add different command to it, and execute them through `Shape::execute()`.

Here's something you could try:

Shapes:

```cpp
struct Shape
{
    std::string name;
    std::function<void(Shape*)> command = [](Shape*){};

    void execute() { command(this); }
};

struct Circle: Shape {
    explicit Circle(double radius)
    : Shape{"circle"}
    , radius{radius}
    {}

    double radius;

    void setCommand(std::function<void(Circle*)> const& command) {
        this->command = [command](Shape* shape){command(static_cast<Circle*>(shape));};
    }
};

struct Triangle: Shape {
    Triangle(double base, double height)
    : Shape{"triangle"}
    , base{base}
    , height{height}
    {}

    double base;
    double height;

    void setCommand(std::function<void(Triangle*)> const& command) {
        this->command = [command](Shape* shape){command(static_cast<Triangle*>(shape));};
    }
};
```

Commands:

```cpp
template<std::derived_from<Shape> T>
void render(T*);

template<>
void render(Circle* circle)
{
    std::cout << circle->name << " is round!\n";
}

template<>
void render(Triangle* triangle)
{
    std::cout << triangle->name << " is sharp!\n";
}

template<std::derived_from<Shape> T>
void print_area(T*);

template<>
void print_area(Circle* circle)
{
    std::cout << "Circle area: " << circle->radius * circle->radius * 3.14 << '\n';
}

template<>
void print_area(Triangle* triangle)
{
    std::cout << "Triangle area: " << triangle->height * triangle->base / 2 << '\n';
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    Circle circle(2);
    Triangle triangle(3, 10);
    auto vec = std::vector<Shape*>{&circle, &triangle};

    std::cout << "Nothing happens here:\n";
    for (const auto& shape : vec)
    {
        shape->execute();
    }

    circle.setCommand(render<Circle>);
    triangle.setCommand(render<Triangle>);
    std::cout << "\nRender:\n";
    for (const auto& shape : vec)
    {
        shape->execute();
    }

    circle.setCommand(print_area<Circle>);
    triangle.setCommand(print_area<Triangle>);
    std::cout << "\nPrint area:\n";
    for (const auto& shape : vec)
    {
        shape->execute();
    }
}
```